# which java is different from %JAVA_HOME%

Tags: java, windows, environment-variables

I am having some issue with the installed JAVA. it seems like it is pointing to a different location even if i changes the JAVA_HOME

The version system is using

```
C:\Users\user123>java -version
java version "1.7.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build pwi3270_27sr1-20140411_01(SR1))
IBM J9 VM (build 2.7, JRE 1.7.0 Windows x86-32 20140410_195893 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
J9VM - R27_Java727_SR1_20140410_1931_B195893
JIT  - tr.r13.java_20140410_61421
GC   - R27_Java727_SR1_20140410_1931_B195893
J9CL - 20140410_195893)
JCL - 20140409_01 based on Oracle 7u55-b13
```

My java home

```
C:\Users\user123>echo %JAVA_HOME%
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_241
```

The java version i am trying to use

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_241\bin>java.exe -version
java version "1.8.0_241"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_241-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.241-b07, mixed mode)
```

the java location the system is using

```
C:\Users\user123>which java
C:/IBM/InformationServer11-5/jdk32/jre/bin/java.exe
```

How do i change this?

Answer (score 0):

Add *%JAVA_HOME%/bin* to your *path* environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure 
    %JAVA_HOME%/bin 
is at the *front* of your **path** environment variable. The items in the **path** variable are priority ordered